# How to fetch elements from a text box and store them in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, associative-array

Can anybody help me out to store data in an array that are fetched from a text box. I need to design a format so that when space will be pressed it should show a different font color before the space character . And the elements after the space should be as usual.

EDIT:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
  var x = 0

  function abc() {
      var a = new Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", ..... "h", "x", "y", "z")
      document.getElementById("type").value = a[x]

      var i = document.getElementById("type").value
      var n = i.charAt(i.length - 1)
      alert(n)
      var n = i.substring(0, i.length - 1)
      document.getElementById("type").value = n.concat(a[x]);
      if (x >= 0) x++
      if (x >= 26) x = 0

  }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<!--<input type="text" name="type" id="type" size="100" onkeyup="abc()">-->

<input type="text" name="type" id="type" size="100" onkeypress="abc()">
<div id="log"></div>
```

ANOTHER ATTEMPT:

```
<script>
  e = jQuery.Event("keypress", {
      keyCode: 32
  });
  jQuery('#type').bind('keydown', function (e) {
      var s = e.which;
      jQuery('#log').html(e.which);

      if (s == 8) { //backspace
          alert('back space');
      }
      if (s == 32) { //space bar
          alert('space');
          var z = document.getElementById("type").value
          jQuery('#type').css({
              'color': 'blue'
          });
      }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your question about changing text color in an input element or storing data in an array?  I don't see how those relate.  Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: can't style parts of text in an input , can only style the whole input. As @gilly3 mentions, subject says one thing, question text something different. Please try to be more concise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can't have multiple colors in an input, you should have no input, just a label, and while user is typing, you capture the event and append to that label.

```
$("body").keypress(function (e) {
    var s = e.which;
    var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

    $("#log").children(":last").append(document.createTextNode(c));

    if (s == 32)  { // Space
        $("#log").children(":last").css({ 'color': 'blue' });
        $("#log").append($("<span/>"));
    }
});
```

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/B5wwP/

Just click in the result area and start typing. I've only done the space feature, you'll need to add other stuff like backspace ...